# Middleware for MediatoR that process OneOf results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation, mediator

I'm writting ASP.NET Core 6 WebAPI. I want to implement CQRS using [Mediator](https://github.com/martinothamar/Mediator), a source-generation based version of MediatR. Validation should be handled by FluentValidation.

I read some tutorials how to implement ValidationBehavior that would validate all request by all relevand validators and exception handling middleware that would catch validation exceptions and convert them into bad request responses.

Now, I want avoid throwing exceptions because it works like a goto. Instead of that, I would like use OneOf to generate coproduct of a response and a validation exception.

Unfortunate, my middleware doesn't work, because `RequestDelegate` returns `void`.

#### How to bypass this problem? What I'm doing wrong? I think it should be feasible.

---

### ValidationBehaviour.cs

```cs
namespace TaskScheduler.Service.PipelineBehaviors;

public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, ValidationCoproduct<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequest<ValidationCoproduct<TResponse>>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators) => _validators = validators;

    public async ValueTask<ValidationCoproduct<TResponse>> Handle(
        TRequest request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        MessageHandlerDelegate<TRequest, ValidationCoproduct<TResponse>> next)
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var failures = (await Task.WhenAll(
            _validators
            .Select(async v => await v.ValidateAsync(validationContext, cancellationToken))))
            .SelectMany(vf => vf.Errors)
            .Where(e => e is not null)
            .ToList();

        return (failures.Any() ? new ValidationCoproduct<TResponse>(new FluentValidation.ValidationException(failures)) : await next(request, cancellationToken))!;
    }
}
```

### ValidationCoproduct

```cs
[GenerateOneOf]
public partial class ValidationCoproduct<T> : OneOfBase<T, FluentValidation.ValidationException>
{
}
```

### OneOfMiddleware

```cs
public class OneOfMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<OneOfMiddleware> _logger;

    public OneOfMiddleware(ILogger<OneOfMiddleware> logger) => _logger = logger;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var result = await next(context); // Error: assigning of void.
    }
}
```

### BrowseQuery

```cs
public record BrowseQuery(BrowseParameters BrowseParameters) : IRequest<ValidationCoproduct<BrowseScheduleTaskResponse>>;
```

### BrowseQueryHandler

```cs
public class BrowseQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<BrowseQuery, ValidationCoproduct<BrowseScheduleTaskResponse>>
{
    public async ValueTask<ValidationCoproduct<BrowseScheduleTaskResponse>> Handle(
        BrowseQuery request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int? count = await GetCountAsync(request.BrowseParameters, cancellationToken);
        var tasks = await GetRequestedScheduleTasks(request, cancellationToken);
        return new BrowseScheduleTaskResponse(tasks, count);
    }
}
```